# How is the Even Possible

Tags: operator-keyword, behavior

I ask this because the program is in fact displaying the MessageBox.
To display the MessageBox the code has to first pass an !=(not equal to) string.Empty criteria.  Then in the very next line it has to pass ==(equal to) string.Empty criteria.  How can the a variable be both equal to and not equal to string.Empty at the same time?

```
if (StatInfo.PosLab.DateSentToTM != string.Empty);
{
    if (StatInfo.PosLab.DateSentToTM == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("How is it even possible to reach this code.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The semicolon after the first `if` makes no sense in this context. In general we don not no anything about the context of your question, e.g. if you wrote it yourself (most likekely not) or if the full programm works as intended or if it shows strange effects.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the string is `!= ""` or `!= null` or `String.equals("")`